# buffer size fails from struct in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, size, buffer

I have written a Modbus library, and near finishing it I have encountered a problem

There is an init structure in which the user can set all the options including the transmit buffer size which will be used to define a buffer with respected size inside a function inside the library (local variable)

here is the code :

in modbus.c :

```
uint8_t MODBUS_SLAVE_DATA[MODBUS_HANDLER->TX_BUFF_SIZE];
```

in modbus.h :

```
typedef struct {
    // GENERAL INFORMATION
    uint8_t  SLAVE_ADDRESS;     
    uint16_t TX_BUFF_SIZE;      
    bool BROADCAST;                     
    // HOLDING REGISTERS
    uint16_t *HOLDING_REGISTERS_W;
    size_t HOLDING_REGISTERS_W_SIZE;
    uint16_t *HOLDING_REGISTERS_R;
    size_t HOLDING_REGISTERS_R_SIZE;
    
    // COILS
    bool *COILS_W;
    size_t COILS_W_SIZE;
    bool *COILS_R;
    size_t COILS_R_SIZE;
    
    // DISCERETE INPUTS
    bool *DISCERETE_INPUT;
    size_t DISCERETE_INPUT_SIZE;
    
    // FUNCTION POINTERS TO HANDLE
    bool(*IO_HANDLER)(uint8_t *,uint16_t);
    bool(*EXCEPTION_HANDLER)(MODBUS_REP,uint8_t,uint8_t);
    // CALL_BACK FUNCTIONS
    bool(*COIL_SINGLE_WRITE_CB)(uint16_t);
    bool(*COIL_MULTIPLE_WRITE_CB)(uint16_t,size_t);
    bool(*HOLDING_REGISTER_SINGLE_WRITE_CB)(uint16_t);
    bool(*HOLDING_REGISTERS_MULTIPLE_WRITE_CB)(uint16_t,size_t);
}MODBUS_INIT;
```

in main.c :

```
MODBUS_INIT modbusInit =
{
    .SLAVE_ADDRESS= 20,
    .BROADCAST  = false,
    .TX_BUFF_SIZE = 1000,
                        
    .HOLDING_REGISTERS_W= modbusRegisters_W,
    .HOLDING_REGISTERS_W_SIZE =(sizeof(modbusRegisters_W)/sizeof(uint16_t)),
    .HOLDING_REGISTERS_R = modbusRegisters_R,
    .HOLDING_REGISTERS_R_SIZE = (sizeof(modbusRegisters_R)/sizeof(uint16_t)),
                            
    .COILS_W = modbusCoil_W,
    .COILS_W_SIZE = sizeof(modbusCoil_W),
    .COILS_R = modbusCoil_W,
    .COILS_R_SIZE = sizeof(modbusCoil_W),
                    
    .DISCERETE_INPUT= modbusInputDiscreat_R,
    .DISCERETE_INPUT_SIZE= sizeof(modbusInputDiscreat_R),
    
    // TRANSMIT POINTER
    .IO_HANDLER = modbusSeerialHandle,
    .EXCEPTION_HANDLER  = modbus_error_Call_back,
    // CALLBACL FUNCTIONS
    .COIL_SINGLE_WRITE_CB= modbus_single_Coil_write_Call_back,
    .COIL_MULTIPLE_WRITE_CB = modbus_multiple_coils_write_Call_back,
    .HOLDING_REGISTER_SINGLE_WRITE_CB= modbus_single_holding_registers_write_Call_back,
    .HOLDING_REGISTERS_MULTIPLE_WRITE_CB= modbus_multiple_holding_registers_write_Call_back,
};
    modbus_slave_handle(dataRecieved,sizeof(dataRecieved),&modbusInit);
```

now if the number 1000 is changed to less than 485 (484 and less), everything works correctly but when the number goes beyond 485 I have a checksum error which means the data is not complete.

now if I hardcode 1000 in modbus.c like code below, everything works fine even more than 1000 works fine

```
uint8_t MODBUS_SLAVE_DATA[1000]; //[MODBUS_HANDLER->TX_BUFF_SIZE];
```

why does the buffer size not work with the size from init struct but works well when it's hardcoded?

this might be useful to answer : I am coding in Keil on Infenion Microcontrollers 32bit ARM XMC1100

Comment: "if the number 1000 is less than 485": when is 1000 less than 485?

Comment: @ScottHunter i edited the question : now if the number 1000 is changed to less than 485 (484 and less)

Comment: Are you really trying to allocate array of 1000 bytes on stack on embedded system? Are you sure you are not causing stack overflow?

Comment: Most likely: You don't have enough (stack) RAM. How much RAM do your static variables use and how much do you have? A hardcoded buffer maybe implemented more efficent or you overwrite other variables you didn't notice the change.

Comment: @user694733 i am going to test mallocing it

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 64 Kbyte and no other library or program is runing on the device , just a serial and my lib

Comment: @S2G Doesn't help, the opposite is the case: `malloc()` probably has a bigger overhead making the RAM problem even worse. That doesn't answer the question.

Comment: This method of allocating memory is not correct at all.
If you want the length of the buffer to be determined during runtime, I recommend you to use heap memory (generally, it is not recommended in embedded systems).
Or define a maximum buffer length in the library header and don't worry about determining the buffer length at runtime.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 In the past I have worked with JSON 10 times of this size and had no problem, I am sure i am not running out of RAM , hardcoded 1000 on size even 5000 works perfectly, just when i try to use the size from struct i have this problem

Comment: @S2G The ARM XMC1100 doesn't have 64 KiB RAM, 64 Kib would be closer (but still wrong). If you have enough RAM, then you didn't provide the code that causes the problem.

Comment: @HamidSalehi  #defining 1000 works perfectly, its just I like hardcoding it, malloc and free are not my choice to go to at this point, i rather go with the stack but if its wrong then i will changed it

Comment: Standard (and most efficient) way to allocate big objects on embedded systems is not stack or heap, but static memory (function or file scope with `static` keyword). But then you cannot use stuct members to set array size (size expression must be integer constant expression).

Comment: By the way, do you really need 1000 bytes from TX buffer? Modbus frames are max 256 bytes if I recall correctly.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 sorry about than, that was flash, ram is 16KB , still i dont think its an overflow , if it was it should have happen even with #define TX_SIZE 1000

Comment: @user694733 exaclty , static can not be valued dynamicly

Comment: @S2G 
In order for the memory allocation operation to happen during runtime, the only way is to use malloc.
Generally, in embedded systems, it is preferred to consider a maximum length for buffers because it is safer.
Therefore, between the heap memory and the definition of maximum buffer size, I prefer the latter.

Comment: What is `MODBUS_HANDLER`?

Comment: @user694733 you are right, and I encounter this problem by chance, how ever at this point is about "why not " , maybe one day the same situation but I actually need the 100

Comment: Are you sure that all 1000 bytes are received? Is it possible that only 485 bytes are received, the other 515 bytes contain their previous garbage values as the receive function doesn't touch them, and you accidentally include all 1000 in the checksum instead of only the 485?

Comment: @ikegami its the struct but i need to change the name of it

Comment: @user253751 This buffer will send the data , its TX buffer , and the PLC will recieve the data , inside the received data by PLC there is a register that says the quantity of bytes that the PLC uses to locate CRC and end of frame,so even if the rest is BS , it should not have a problem , however my problem is not 1000 not workign ! its 100 FROM INIT STRUCT is not working, otherwise, even 5000 is working.

Comment: Please be more specific. (Declaration and definition. You can leave out fields other than `TX_BUFF_SIZE`) You say `MODBUS_HANDLER->TX_BUFF_SIZE` doesn't work, but you're not providing any info about it!

Comment: `uint8_t MODBUS_SLAVE_DATA[MODBUS_HANDLER->TX_BUFF_SIZE];` isn't valid C and that's one of the roots to the problem. Another root of your problems is that XMC1100 is a _Cortex M0 microcontroller_, it is not a PC. You only have 16kb of RAM total, so you can't just toss huge amounts away, nor can you allocate huge amounts on the stack, nor can you use heap allocation. Does this really need to sit in read-write memory or could you have stored (parts of) it as a read-only table in flash?

Comment: @ikegami i edited the question, now its much more code in it , please check , thank you

Comment: @Lundin thanks, its a buffer for TX, for example, if PLC wants to red Holding Register start in 0 and end in 123 (it's going to be 123*2 bytes + CRC and some OFFSET on start for function code and address), so at a worst case scenario PLC might want to access 255 bytes, i need to make these bytes and make CRC from it put it in a buffer and give buffer pointer to the IO_HANDLE function pointer which deals with Uart HW , this way Library is portable and no HW dependent code is inside of it ,

Comment: The MCU could probably calculate the data as it goes, since an ARM is so much faster than the standard UART baudrates. Either way `uint8_t MODBUS_SLAVE_DATA[MODBUS_HANDLER->TX_BUFF_SIZE];` is always wrong - if this is a file scope variable (could have been declared `static`) then it's invalid C. If this is a local variable then it can be made valid C but making it local means that you just blew your stack to pieces.

Comment: @Lundin Having the same stack size as magic number apparently doesn't blow the stack, see comments before. How to explain? Would compiler then allocate outside of stack, albeit being locally defined?

Comment: @Lundin is a local variable inside modbus.c in a function, does not have the static keyword but it is local and not accessible from main.c , if i decleare static then it can not be given size dynamicly , if this is wrong why only after 485 will it crash , and how can i have a dynamic buffer in an Embedded system ? only using malloc? (by the way for this particular project i dont need more than 256 anyway, but i want to learn something)

Comment: @Aconcagua Undefined behavior is undefined...

Comment: @S2G What _is_ your stack size anyway? That's highly relevant info and the first thing you should look for. Best practices in embedded systems include: never declare big buffers on the stack and never use dynamic allocation. "and how can i have a dynamic buffer in an Embedded system" By placing it in `.bss` and giving it a fixed size to cover the worst-case scenario.

Comment: @S2G To be precise: `malloc` within MCU is not impossible per se – but potentially needs to be explicitly enabled in project settings and you might need to reserve some memory for heap as well (I believe to recall having seen at least the latter option in Keil years ago). And it is a critical operation, doing that often can easily result in fragmented memory and in consequence failure on some allocation later on in the programme run. That's why it is generally strongly advised against.

Comment: Also... "when the number goes beyond 485 I have a checksum error" What do you mean "checksum error"? From whom, where does that come from? RAM doesn't typically come with checksums at all unless you implement it manually.

Comment: @Aconcagua Using `malloc` on a single core MCU is just nonsense. A long list of reasons regarding why that is so can be found here: [Why should I not use dynamic memory allocation in embedded systems?](https://electrical.codidact.com/posts/286121)

Comment: @Lundin Undefined is only if stack actually overflows. Consuming 6% of memory at once might be problematic, but not necessarily...

Comment: @Aconcagua Except stacks on Cortex M0 are usually around 1-2kb large and this is supposedly a whole MODBUS stack so there will be lot of things competing over stack space. Kind of cramped MCU to use for such a project... but possible if you know what you are doing, I've shoe-horned CANopen stacks inside even smaller MCUs.

Comment: @Lundin Still it's not *impossible*, and even some functional safety standards *do* allow it (would need to look up which ones, though), but limited to initialisation phase only. Meaningful, though, is another matter, and there I agree on ;)

Comment: @Aconcagua Although using MODBUS and functional safety sounds like contradicting requirements to begin with...

Comment: @Lundin Stack size is configurable, too, within Keil. We could reserve all memory not required for code as stack. But that might be an important setting to look at!

Comment: @Lundin That's a good point. In those projects we used SPI, I²C or CAN instead, and albeit allowed, we never allocated dynamically ;)

Comment: @S2G By the way: Where do you get the size for dynamically anyway? More memory than the MCU offers you cannot allocate, of course, so how would you want to handle if that size received from wherever is too large?

Comment: @Aconcagua Allocating as large a stack as possible and also making sure the stack grows into a non-harmful memory area. Some default stupid memory maps for Cortex M have the stack overflowing into .bss/.data which is kind of a big rookie mistake as well.

Comment: @Lundin Hm... If i recall correctly there's not a protection against anyway, and e.g. a non-tail-call-optimised endless recursion would end up there anyway, no matter if stack is large or not. We needed to provide some analysis why we couldn't run out of stack (no recursions, maximum call depths, ...).

Comment: @S2G Possibly we are talking about an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) – **why** do you need dynamic allocation at all? What do you actually intend to solve with?

Comment: Re "*now its much more code in it*", But I asked about `MODBUS_HANDLER`, and you didn't add anything about `MODBUS_HANDLER`.  You say `MODBUS_HANDLER->TX_BUFF_SIZE` doesn't work, but you're not providing any info about it!

Comment: @S2G Is `sizeof(bool)` 1 on you machine?